# How can I sort/organize/categorize Google Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I want to categorize my google chrome extensions but I don't quite have a way/means to do so.

If anyone has any suggestions please feel free to let me know.

I'd like to order them by category like iOS folder names. Eg. Productivity, Social, Utilities, etc...

Comment: In what way? Do you mean in the 3 dot menu, in the extension page? As far as I'm aware neither of those are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use an extension such as Extensity or SimpleExtManager to create extension groups.

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensity/jjmflmamggggndanpgfnpelongoepncg
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simpleextmanager/kniehgiejgnnpgojkdhhjbgbllnfkfdk